# JSONArray(String json) returns "Infinite" when parsing some unquoted (invalid) JSON

Tags: java, android, json

A curiosity:

```
JSONArray rfidArray1 = new JSONArray("[047c04fae63684]");
```

returns a `JSONArray` whose first value is a `Double` with value of `Infinity`, whereas:

```
JSONArray rfidArray1 = new JSONArray("[04b2b6f2443680]");
```

returns a `JSONArray` whose first value is a `String` with value of `04b2b6f2443680`.

This is clearly invalid JSON which should throw a JSONException, but instead it sporadically returns broken values. It seems to be lenient with some values and return a "proper" JSONArray, but with some others it does not. Here are some more values:

Returns first value of `Double` with value of `Infinity`:

```
"[047c04fae63684]"
"[042579FAE63680]"
"[048C22FAE63684]"
"[049360FAE63680]"
```

Returns first value of `String` with 'proper' value:

```
"[04bb97d27c3680]"
"[04BB97D27C3680]"
"[04337FF2443681]"
"[04b2b6f2443680]"
"[0447E3FAE63680]"
"[\"047c04fae63684\"]"
"[\"049360FAE63680\"]"
```

I'm using Android 4.4.2 API level 19.

Comment: what happens if you do: `JsonArray json = new JsonArray(); json.put("047c04fae63684");`

Comment: I correctly end up with the same value as if I did `JSONArray rfidArray10 = new JSONArray("[\"047c04fae63684\"]");` (`String` with 'proper' value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'double' values contain the letter E, which is valid double syntax IF the parser recognized hexadecimal, which `JSONArray` probably does. `E` means in the floating point world as `times 10 to the power of`

`numbers1[E/e]numbers2` is parsed as:

`numbers1 * (10 ^ numbers2)`, or

`numbers1 times 10 to the power of numbers2`

Where numbers[1/2] represent any combination of hexadecimal digits. Sooo....

`047c04fae63684` is the same as

`047c04fa * (10 ^ 64684)` and double does not have enough data space to hold that exponent, so it overflows and returns `Infinity`.

Meanwhile the `JSONArray` parser has no clue what to with `"[04b2b6f2443680]"`, so im geussing it assumes that because it contains non digits, that it must be a string and it returns it as a `String`.

For `"[\"049360FAE63680\"]"` you enclosed the array value in quotes so the parser automatically sees them and says 'Hey, thats a string, lets just return that' and doesn't do anything else.

Sorry if the data is inaccurate, I have a bad head cold.

Comment: Amazing! I thought it could be something like that, but I didn't expect 'to the power of'. Congratulations on an expertly explained answer, and thanks :)